# Accessing inner exceptions when building using csc.exe

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, csc

I am compiling a project using `csc.exe`, with the `/analyzer:` flag pointing to the paths of `ErrorProne.Net.CoreAnalyzers.dll` and `ErrorProne.Net.Core.dll`, which are built from my clone of the library [here](https://github.com/SergeyTeplyakov/ErrorProne.NET).

However, I see several error messages like these:

> "warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer
>   ErrorProne.NET.AsyncAnalyzers.ConcurrentCollectionAnalyzer cannot be
>   created from
>   C:\Repos\RoslynExample\RoslynExample\ErrorProne.Net.CoreAnalyzers.dll
>   : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
>
> "warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer
>   ErrorProne.NET.AsyncAnalyzers.AddConfigureAwaitAnalyzer cannot be
>   created from
>   C:\Repos\RoslynExample\RoslynExample\ErrorProne.Net.CoreAnalyzers.dll
>   : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

etc.

I would like to get more debug information, so that I know exactly when and where these errors are thrown, as well as their inner exceptions. As of now, these error messages on their own are useless.

**It is important that I am able to print the stack traces (especially the inner exceptions) to console, or write it to file**.

How can I get a copy of the stack trace?

***UPDATE:***

I figured out the cause of these errors by 1) creating a console application which runs the analyzers built from my clone of the `Error.Net` source code, 2) disabling `Just My Code`, and 3) breaking on all exceptions. While it is great to finally figure out what the problem is, it still leaves my original question unanswered: **How can I get access to the inner exceptions (so that I can display them later) just by running `csc.exe`?**

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to csc?

Comment: Maybe you could add to the AppDomain.FirstChanceException event within your analyzer code and investigate the exceptions (log or display them)? Be aware though, that implementing the event handler can lead to a stackoverflow so check implementation examples on this site.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to turn on Trace output?

```
     csc -r:System.dll -d:TRACE -d:DEBUG=FALSE MyApplication.cs
```

Maybe this article will be usefull for you [How to: Compile Conditionally with Trace and Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-compile-conditionally-with-trace-and-debug)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I turned on tracing and unfortunately still did not have access to the inner exceptions.